# Is "the integrity of the file x has not been verified" an user error or an issue with a Chocolatey package?

Tags: chocolatey

I get the error when installing [Java SE Runtime Environment](https://chocolatey.org/packages/jre8) (with [AutoHotkey (Portable)](https://chocolatey.org/packages/autohotkey.portable) too), the sixth most downloaded Chocolatey package:

```
The integrity of the file 'jre8Install.exe' from 'http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211997' has not been verified by a checksum in the package scripts.
```

Is installation safe? Is there a problem with this package or in my system?

```
Chocolatey v0.10.0
Installing the following packages:
jre8
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.

jre8 v8.0.101 [Approved]
The package jre8 wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider setting
 'allowGlobalConfirmation'. Run 'choco feature -h' for more details.
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[N]o/[P]rint): y

Searching if new version exists...
Downloading jre8
  from 'http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211997'
Progress: 100% - Completed download of C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\jre8\8.0.101\jre8Install.exe (52.63 MB).
Download of jre8Install.exe (52.63 MB) completed.
WARNING: Missing package checksums are not allowed (by default for HTTP/FTP,
 HTTPS when feature 'allowEmptyChecksumsSecure' is disabled) for
 safety and security reasons. Although we strongly advise against it,
 if you need this functionality, please set the feature
 'allowEmptyChecksums' ('choco feature enable -n
 allowEmptyChecksums')
 or pass in the option '--allow-empty-checksums'.
The integrity of the file 'jre8Install.exe' from 'http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211997' has not been verified by a checksum in the package scripts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chocolatey 0.10.0 requires checksum verification for all packages (see [Checksum requirement and enhancements](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/112)).

You see this error, because the author of the `jre8` package didn't provide the checksum.

To force installation of the package you should put `--allow-empty-checksums` parameter:

```
choco install jre8 --allow-empty-checksums
```

You can also contact a maintainer and ask to add support for checksum verification:

[image: Contact Maintainers]

Comment: Do you consider forcing installation unsafe? I guess I can trust Chocolatey packages.

Comment: Right now it means the file is being downloaded over HTTP without verifying the file's checksum. If you were to go download the file yourself over HTTP, you would be the same amount of secure if you didn't also verify the integrity of the file. Things like DNS poisoning and open Wifi networks are places where MITM (Man in the middle) attacks can easily occur. If you trust your network and you don't have any issues, then it is less likely to happen.

Comment: What some folks do not realize is that these packages up on the public community repository are subject to copyright laws/distribution rights, so they do not always contain the software that the packages represent and must download them from the official distribution points. This means a download from some location. Checksums in pkgs serve to ensure you are getting the file that the maintainers (and moderators) intended.